# Adding goals to reports/dashboards?

Tags: dashboard, custom-report-type

i am setting up some reports for the creation of dashboard that show revenue etc vs. goals for different time periods. I am currently working on quarterly revenue vs. goal broken down by Account owner.  I set up a matrix of opportunity owner vs. amount for closed won opportunities in current quarter.  I have this displayed as a bar chart and want to be able to add a goal value for each of the 5 opportunity owners in the report and compare that to actual revenue. What is the easiest way to add these goal values?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you already have a field in your data that contains the goals or some "factor" used against a previous period's closed-won opportunities that's been set for each user, there isn't an easy way to do what you're asking.

The only way I can possibly think of would be to create a formula field based on an existing field and you might be able to use that. However, you'd need it to operate on a custom field unless each account owner's goals used the same constant as the "factor" to use on the reference value you'd use for creating their goal (e.g. Amount of previous period's closed-won opportunities) since the formula would apply to all of your account owners unless it was contained in a custom field for each one (or perhaps each account).

In the [Reporting Workbook](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/workbook_analytics.pdf) or other documentation, take a look at "Create a Formula using the PARENTGROUPVAL Summary Function" (Tutorial 3, step 2) and " Create a Formula Using the PREVGROUPVAL Summary Function" (Tutorial 3, step 3) as those would seem to be the formula functions that would apply to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tip on Creating Sales vs. Goal Reports and Dashboards in the Salesforce success community? https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hs6gAAA